# How do I "Hide()" a Modal WPF Window without it closing?

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog

I have a WPF window that is run on a background thread as a sort of "notifier window"... when an event is raised, it displays a message... a user clicks the "Snooze" button and I call `this.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed`

The very moment that I hide the window (either by calling `this.Hide()` or setting the `Visibility` as mentioned above)... the "ShowDialog()" code releases the window and closes it.

This is absolutely a bug in the WPF code (which I've identified via reflector)... but my question remains. Has anyone been able to come up with a work-around for this issue?

I've tried many things and am now reaching out to ya'll smart people :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, and as quickly as that - my boss (old C++ goofy guy that he is) figured out the answer.

Here *was* the code inside of my background thread (which is set to STA mode):

```
// Show dialog - keeps the thread open and shows the window! Yay!!!
new BeamUI.Notifier.NotifierWindow().ShowDialog();
```

And here is the modification, that strangely enough works perfectly :)

```
// Show... hmm, that shows the window... but how do I keep this thread open?
new BeamUI.Notifier.NotifierWindow().Show();

// ZOMG - a line of code that JUST keeps the thread (and msgpump) going!!!
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

And that's it.

This kinda thing makes me hate C++ people though, and makes me want to just say "if you just built it right in the first place I wouldn't have to look for a work-around!" (j/k)

Comment: As an explanation of why this works... the ShowDialog bug that I mentioned in the question didn't dispose of the window, but it just released the thread-message-pump-hold-it-open-dealio. So, now that we are no longer relying on said "dealio"... hide/show/hide/show is all good :)

Comment: You don't need a separate thread for a top-level window (Show). The main UI thread will handle this itself, unless there are circumstances that you have not told us of.

Comment: There is more - the notifications need their own context because even if the main UI has a message box (another "ShowDialog" window), this notifier window needs to be able to respond to clicks, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can't hide a modal dialog. That's like asking, "How do I get to 100mph in reverse?" You don't, you drive the car forwards.

Use Show, not ShowDialog. Alternately you can simply re-ShowDialog when it needs to become visible again.

Comment: You can hide a modal dialog in WinForms... there is a bug *only* in WPF windows.

Comment: Ok, the car analogy was lame, but the point is this: A modal dialog is, by definition, a dialog that is displayed and which blocks the user from interacting with any other parts of your application until they complete the dialog. How does hiding of such a beast even make sense?

Comment: It's because it's a secondary "program inside the program" really. The user uses the app... but the server can communicate down to the user and absolutely requires and needs an exclusive context... meaning - MessageBox.Show("Hello") on the main UI thread *cannot* (by business requirements) thwart the server sending down a "notification".

Comment: Hiding a dialog to make an user selection on the canvas is used in CAD programs like AutoCAD to select a point for example.

Comment: @KobyDuck These are modal dialog boxes. When they are displayed, the window below them is no longer accessible. AutoCAD has a very specific behavior, because there is a command line.

Answer (score 2):

Timothy's Answer is good. I just needed for my scenerio to add the following

```
window.Closed += new EventHandler(window_Closed);
window.Show();
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
```

and then in the event...

```
void window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ExitAllFrames();
}
```

I needed to do this because it was hanging on the Run after the form was really closed.

Answer (score 2):

1. In order to show modal window always use `ShowDialog()`.
2. Use `Close()` instead of `Hide()`.
3. Handle the `FormClosing` event like that:

```
    private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: This seems like a Winforms solution. WPF used Visiblity instead of Visible.

Comment: What if the same dialog is shown again an exception is thrown.